# How to write a command line output to file (e.g.filename) but if it already exists create and write to file with appended name (e.g.filename(1))?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm running a program from the Windows command line (using a batch script) and writing the output to a file. Like so:

example.exe > filename.csv

If filename.csv already exists, this overwrites the file with the new output. Ideally, what I want is if the file already exists, the output is saved to an altered filename such as filename(1).csv.

Is this possible from the command line?

Comment: You didn't say what operating system.

Comment: Hi thanks, my bad. Using Windows, have added to post also.

Answer (score 0):

Save the program below as GetOutput.bat:

```
@echo off
rem GetOutput.bat program destFile
set "destName=%~N2"
set i=0
:nextName
   if not exist "%destName%%~X2" goto runProg
   set /A i+=1
   set "destName=%~N2 (%i%)"
   goto nextName
:runProg
%1 > "%destName%%~X2"
```

For example:

```
GetOutput.bat example.exe filename.csv
```